# Rails: Changes in services not reflected until restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Edit: The question originally was about a `NameError` which was due to not autoloading automatically in Rails < 6. I've since moved this class to `app/services`.

---

I added a folder called `stripe_events` inside `app/services`.

I'm using this for Stripe Webhooks. It works, however, when I edit my class, the change doesn't happen until I restart Rails.

I've tried adding it to my `spring.rb`

```
%w(
  .ruby-version
  .rbenv-vars
  tmp/restart.txt
  tmp/caching-dev.txt
  app/services/**
  app/services
).each { |path| Spring.watch(path) }
```

Comment: Require it explicitly with `require 'stripe_events/charge_failed'`.

Comment: Thank you @max, I hadn't thought of that. That solved my issue, however, I'm back to where I was earlier before I moved things around - Changes in my class are not reflected until I manually restart the Rails server. Perhaps you know what may be the  issue?

Comment: Thats how classes that are not autoloaded behave. You can add lib to the autoload paths or move it to `/app/stripe_events/charge_failed.rb` which is in the autoload paths.

Comment: @max I placed `stripe_events` in `/app`, however, it was unable to find. I placed in my `services` folder instead, and it was able to find the class without requiring. But I still have the issue of changes inside not reflecting until I restart rails. Any clue why?

Comment: @good_afternoon In your `config/application.rb`, try adding - `config.autoload_paths.push(*Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '**/') ])`. Then restart your `rails s` and then test if it works?